# Merging in R with data.table with two columns

Tags: r, merge

I am fairly new to using `data.table` but I am using it since I have heard it is faster than `data.frame` and plan to loop.

I am trying to merge raster data (which comes with longitude "x", latitude "y", and temperature information) onto a master dataset, which is just all possible combinations of "x" and "y" for this particular country I am looking at.

For some reason, `data.frame` works (the temperature information is merged in. Some missing information but that's to be expected) while `data.table` does not (the temperature variable is "added" but all information is missing). I think it has to do something with the fact that I am merging with two columns, or maybe the data isn't sorted the right way, but I'm not completely sure.

Below is my code

```
    # Set common parameters
    x <- rep(seq(-49.975,49.975, by = 0.05), times = 2000)
    y <- rep(seq(-49.975,49.975, by = 0.05), each = 2000)
    xy <- cbind(x,y)

    ## What works
    # Create data frame, then subset to possible coordinates of country
    df_xy <- data.frame(xy)
    eth_df_xy <- subset(df_xy, df_xy$x >= 30 & df_xy$x <= 50 & df_xy$y >=0 & df_xy$y <= 20)
    # Bring in raster dataset
    examine <- print(paste0(dir_tif, files[[1]]))
    sds <- raster(examine)
    x <- rasterToPoints(sds)
    df_x <- data.frame(x)
    # Merge
    eth_df_xy <- merge(df_x, eth_df_xy, by = c("x","y"), all.x = F, all.y=T)

    ## What doesn't work but seems intuitive
    # Create data table, then subset to possible coordinates of country (as above)
    dt_xy <- data.table(xy)
    eth_dt_xy <- subset(dt_xy, dt_xy$x >= 30 & dt_xy$x <= 50 & dt_xy$y >=0 & dt_xy$y <= 20)
    # Bring in raster dataset (from above, skip to fourth step)
    dt_x <- data.table(x)
    # Merge
    eth_dt_xy <- merge(dt_x, eth_dt_xy, by = c("x","y"), all.x = F, all.y=T)
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider using dplyr instead of data.table. dplyr code tends to be much more readable and is usually easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Claus. Unfortunately, I just tried `left_join(eth_df_xy, df_x)` (after recreating `eth_df_xy`) but this did not seem to work (the temperature variable was all NA. It was merging by the right things though, as I was told in red letters that "Joining, by = c("x", "y")").

Comment: Please provide a small example that we can run.